# Where can I ask questions about harmful products?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which SE site, can I ask questions about how harmful cosmetic products really are? In my situation it would be hair color and I want to know if the more expensive one really is better for my hair (asking due to hair loss).

I thought about asking in Health SE, Chemistry SE or Skeptics. Which is the best site to ask?

Comment: Health sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

To quote [Health.SE's Asking page](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you can ask questions about "Environmental or nutritional factors that affect health".

Extrapolating from that, the effects of certain dyes on hair loss seems perfectly on topic there.

Comment: Note that you'll want to be careful about *how* you ask.  "Is chemical X known to cause hair loss" is acceptable, "Is my shampoo causing my hair to fall out" is not.